# Return current user on details

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an API view, to handle user management using django rest framework version 2.3.10 with django 1.6. I tried to build a `ModelViewSet` which based on the URL pk value it would return either current user or public user.

I tried to add a dispatch function which will assigned pk to current user, but it seems like this function is running too soon that its always seeing the user as anonymous

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrCreateOnly, )

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('pk') == 'current' and not request.user.is_anonymous():
            kwargs['pk'] = request.user.pk
        resp = super(CurrentUserViewSet, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return resp
```

I tried to do the below, which works

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrCreateOnly, )

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk') == u'current' and not request.user.is_anonymous():
            self.kwargs['pk'] = request.user.pk
        return super(CurrentUserViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

but, I don't want to override each and every function on several `ModelViewSet` classes I have, so, is there a way to use something similar to the dispatcher whereby I can check if the pk is equal to "current" and then assign current user to it?

Another question, how can I change the returned fields programmatically? for example when querying current user I want to include the first and last name from the user model, but when querying by primary key, I want first and last name to not return as response? any suggestions on how todo that?

Comment: For future readers this is discussed here: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1322

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem I solved it by using method "initial" instead of "dispatch"

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrCreateOnly, )

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # logic - code #
        if kwargs.get('pk') == 'current' and not request.user.is_anonymous():
            kwargs['pk'] = request.user.pk
        # end #
        resp = super(CurrentUserViewSet, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return resp
```

see " dispatch " 
method in https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py
for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Override `viewsets.ModelViewSet` class with your pk check implementation and use that new class, something like this:

```
class GenericUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk') == u'current' and not request.user.is_anonymous():
            self.kwargs['pk'] = request.user.pk
        return super(CurrentUserViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)


class UserViewSet(GenericUserViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrCreateOnly, )
```

And for the second question, perhaps creating two serializers (public and current) and changing `serializer_class` to either one of them in `init` of `GenericUserViewSet` may do the trick, I haven't tested this but it's an idea:

```
class GenericUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk') == u'current' and not request.user.is_anonymous():
            self.serializer_class = UserSerializer
        else:
            self.serializer_class = PublicUserSerializer
        super(GenericUserViewSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Second part is mostly right, but override `get_serializer_class` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to save the current user to your DB model, yes?

If so this should be fairly easy to fix, just add this method to your views:

```
def pre_save(self, obj):
    obj.user = self.request.user
```

This will execute just before the model is saved. I use this all the time and it works great.

The other thing you can do is write a mixin class in a generic way that does want you want then inherit it in each of the views you need it in. Assuming that is that you have a solution that works, but just don't want to mimic you code all over the place.